# Script doesn't work if entry begins with a 'x.'

Tags: google-sheets

I have a script that deletes rotes that contain certain keywords, but it appears that it returns an error ("Those rows are out of bounds.") whenever the format of the content of a cell is 'x.name@email.com' (where 'x' is any letter) but not, for instance 'xname@email.com'.

For example, I wish to remove all instances of 'robot' in a list of emails and the script works finely if the term occurs as "robot@email.com", but I get the out-of-bounds error if the format is 'a.robot@email.com'.

Here is the code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      options = [
        {name:"Remove Duplicates", functionName:"removeDuplicates"},
        {name:"Remove Keywords", functionName:"removeKeywords"}
      ];
  ss.addMenu("Functions", options);
}



function removeKeywords() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {

    var row = values[i];

    if (row[0].toLowerCase().indexOf("robot") > -1) {
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
}
```

Any idea why I get the 'out-of-bounds' error when the term occurs in the 'x.robot@email.com' format, where 'x' is any letter?

Comment: Please post a link to a copy of your spreadsheet with your script. Did you write the script yourself? It contains some seemingly unnecessary transformations, like the parseInt() invocation, maybe that is the reason.

Comment: @ttarchala, here is the link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jw2ayvYI9ue7om1UsNKbHTpuag6R7hiJk_dsPoqSYwk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The script is set to delete rows containing 'admin' and 'robot'.  I wonder if the error is prompted by the fact that a keyword occurs twice in the same cell.  Has anyone ever heard of this happening?

Comment: I made a copy of your spreadsheet and a copy of your function and it's running correctly on my side, regardless of the contents. I'm not sure how to help you at this point. Perhaps try making a copy (a fresh spreadsheet) yourself. Or perhaps try recording exactly the steps you are executing to run this function.